# Why must a Microsoft bot expose a publicly accessible HTTPS endpoint?

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

According to Microsoft Bot Framework's FAQ's, a bot must expose a publicly accessible HTTPS endpoint. (see below)

"Can I host my bot on my own servers? 
Yes. Your bot can be hosted anywhere on the Internet. On your own servers, in Azure, or in any other datacenter. The only requirement is that the bot must expose a publicly-accessible HTTPS endpoint."

My question is why must it expose a publicly accessible HTTPS endpoint?

Answer (score 2):

Simply due to the architecture: your bot will communicate with the channels through the Bot Connector, which is not hosted on your side but on Microsoft side:

[image: https://blog.cellenza.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/architecture-resize-1080x525.png]

So the Connector must be able to talk to your endpoint, which must be public.